# Visual Studio - find results in a dockable window

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would like my "Ctrl+f" results to be shown in a dockable window rather than having to cycle through  them. I saw someone does it, but didn't ask him how..

How? (-:

(I'm using VS 2010 if that matters..) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dock the find window that your are getting your results to - when opening the dialog, you can expand the `Result options` section to tell VS which result window to use.

Use Find In Files (<kbd>CTRL + Shift + F</kbd> or `Edit -> Find And Replace -> Find in Files`).